# Menu Not Showing In Second Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I am opening a second activity from my menubar and displaying a 3-dot menu in the second activity as well, which, doesn't seem to show up!

Here is the activity2menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_2_menu"
        android:title="@string/action_new"></item>
</menu>
```

And here is the activity2 code:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity2_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.activity_2_menu){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
}
```

Where lies the problem? 
Thanks!
P.S. I know it has been asked a lot of times, but none of the other solutions in stack overflow worked :(

Comment: Are you using a toolbar or actionbar in the activity2? If not, the menu won't be able to inflate anywhere.

Comment: The code seems correct.  It should display the menu. I am not sure what other part in your code.

Comment: @jyanks I tried adding `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` to `onCreate();` this crashes the acitivity.

Comment: Do you have a toolbar with that id in your activity_2.xml layout?

Comment: Use an icon and showAsAction attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you haven't actually specified a toolbar to inflate the menu options onto. Your menu creation code looks correct.

In your activity_2.xml layout, you need to have either:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Or:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

NOTE: The  will only work if you have a file in your res/layout folder called toolbar.xml

You then need to call:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  

    if(toolbar != null) {  
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Comment: What is toolbar.xml? When the new activity is created it should be having the menu option, why do we need to define this toolbar thing explicitly?

Comment: In AppCompatActivity there is no actionbar that is pre-set as in ActionBarActivity. toolbar.xml is simply a layout file that contains the <Toolbar> element in the code above.